# SQL Server transaction log reported full when it isn't

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

*The transaction log for database 'WebDB' is full.*

No, it isn't. Its 90% free. The transaction log backups run normally. My hardware guy tells me the hardware is running perfectly, with plenty of space. SQL Server 2008 SP3, but not R2.

I'm a developer, we no longer have a DBA. So it falls to me to try and fix this.